# Run script upon starting terminal

Tags: shell

When a user logs in as a particular user, how do I make a terminal/shell immediately run a script?

I have a script which include some alias commands and I would like the script to run when a unique user account is run.

For reference I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the script to run at login, then adding the bash commands or call to another shell script would go into .bash_profile as the first answer indicates. Depending on the Linux distro, you might have to create this file in your home directory.

If you want all process that launch after you login to have access to whatever shell script you wanted run at login time, those bash commands or call to another shell script should go into .bashrc.

Edit: (Based on question)

Make sure you create the .bash_profile in /home/you-home-directory (~).

To make sure it works, you could log out and back in or enter source .bash_profile.

You could always put a debug echo statement into .bash_profile, like echo "Running", and make sure you see that.

To make sure .bash_profile is in /home/your-home, ls -la ~/.bash_profile

Comment: this looks like the answer I need, however .bash_profile still isn't being executed. do I need to give this file particular permissions?

Comment: Did you log out and then back in? Or, did you try source .bash_profile? You can always put a temporary echo "I got here" in the .bash_profile just as a debug statement. Just don't forget to remove it. I checked my .bashrc, and it's got non-execute privs. It won't hurt you to chmod 755 .bash_profile, but I don't think it's necessary. Also make sure when you do ls -la ~/.bash_profile that you see the file. (That is that it's in your home directory.)

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to why it is not working, so please let us know. I've gotten into more hot water with bash shell scripts. I can empathize.

Comment: I've logged out and back in, tested using source .bash_profile and the script works. also tried a simple echo for debugging. chmod is 755. still it's not working.

Comment: I'm confused. Are your creation of and/or edits to .bash_profile working and the script being called is not working? If so, I suggest your posting that as a separate question or at least show us how you're calling that script from .bash_profile. (As to file permissions, .bashrc is rw-r-r, so .bash_profile is also not marked executable.)

Comment: I've created the .bath_profile file but it doesn't execute when I log in as that user. the permissions for the file are rw-r-r and it still doesn't work

Comment: You've spelled out .bath_profile in your comment. Is that the real file name, or a misspelling? If you are cd'd to home, what does ls -la .bash_profile reveal?

Comment: typo,sorry. the file is definitely called .bash_profile. doing an ls -la reveals:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dan dan 13 2012-02-05 19:33 .bash_profile

Comment: What distro of Linux is this? Do you have a .profile in /home/your-home-directory ? Have you tried an echo in the .bash_profile? If all else fails, call the shell script or execute the commands of the shell script in .bashrc. If you run man bash, it should indicate all possible init files that could be, but may not actually be present, and in which order they are read.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user is setup with bash shell, you can add the shell script to ".bash_profile" in the users home directory.

Comment: He's got one. We're trying to find out why it won't run.